# Custom theme development from scratch in moodle 2.7

Tags: moodle

I am working in a project to create a Moodle 2.7 from scratch. I have done few theme customizations for Moodle 2.6 but I can't find any reference for Moodle 2.7. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between creating a theme for moodle 2.6 and moodle 2.7.

In moodle 2.7, the way of creating theme is same as it was earlier.

You may already knew this, For [Creating moodle theme](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme)

Before moodle 2.7 there is a standard theme in moodle is called 'standard', and in latest moodle 2.7, the standard 'theme' is called 'clean' which is based on bootstrap.

There is a difference between creating a moodle's simple and bootstrap theme, because:-

In simple theme you can get the layout file like "frontpage.php", "general.php" etc and

In bootstrap theme you can get the layout file like "columns1.php", "columns2.php", "columns3.php" etc.

But version makes no difference, you can choose a way to make  a theme for moodle 2.7 as you have chosen for moodle 2.6.